# Can't check custom status of discord.js user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a system in discord.js version 12 where if you have my vanity invite in your status, you get a supporter role

Whenever I try this it always says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Here is my code

```js
const roleID = "MyRoleID"
const inviteLink = "discord.gg/MyVanityInvite"

client.on('presenceUpdate', (_oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  const member = newPresence.member
  if (member) {
    // Ignore members who already have the role
    if (!member.roles.cache.has(roleID)) {
      console.log(newPresence)
      const customStatus = newPresence.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'CUSTOM_STATUS').state
      if (customStatus) {
        if (customStatus.includes(inviteLink)) {
          member.roles.add(roleID)
            .catch(console.error)
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

If I try to log the newPresence is logs an array
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<Presence>.activities`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities) returns an array of activities, you don't need to get the `cache`, just find directly like:

```js
newPresence.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'CUSTOM_STATUS').state
```

Comment: Still getting the same error :/

Comment: Try to log newPresence.activities

Comment: It returned undefined

Comment: And only newPresence?

Comment: That returned a long table array

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to the question?

Comment: `newPresence.activites` should be `newPresence.activities`

Comment: It already is that

Comment: Update your code with your new one so

Comment: It worked, but now it says `state is undefined`

Comment: If you remove state and log customStatus?

Comment: Same message as before

Comment: Not possible, screenshot it

Comment: I was still logging the other one, another smaller array has been logged this time

Comment: Replace the screenshot by the new one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240044/discussion-between-cmb-and-leau).

Comment: In the end this did end up solving my problem *well, after spending about 4 months testing it*. Thank you